# Is there a way to fetch the incoming/outgoing/heartbeat messages in the code?

Tags: quickfixj

I am using QuickFIX/J (1.6.4). I can see all the messages segregated very properly (incoming/outgoing/event)

```
<20180504-07:32:14, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Session FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB->  schedule is daily, 00:00:00-UTC - 00:00:00-UTC) <20180504-07:32:14, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Created session: FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> ) <20180504-07:32:15, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Configured socket addresses for session: [/x.x.x.x:xxxx]) <20180504-07:32:15, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (MINA session created: local=/y.y.y.y:yyyy, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketSession, remote=/x.x.x.x:xxxx) <20180504-07:32:16, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , outgoing> (8=FIX.4.29=7935=A34=149=CLIENT252=20180504-07:32:16.386) <20180504-07:32:16, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Initiated logon request) <20180504-07:32:16, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , incoming> (8=FIX.4.29=8035=A34=1) <20180504-07:32:16, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Logon contains ResetSeqNumFlag=Y, resetting sequence numbers to 1) <20180504-07:32:16, FIX.4.2:CLIENT2/SUB-> , event> (Received logon)
```

---

However, I am unable to find a way to fetch these segregated messages as-is in my code.

PS: I dig deeper, and reached `ScreenLogFactory.java` which ultimately seems to log what I see on console logs. But could not find a way to extract those incoming/outgoing messages in my code.

**Edit1:** 
How can I capture session level messages?

Comment: Have you tried catching these in your `quickfix.Application.fromAdmin` and `quickfix.Application.toAdmin` implementations? See [Creating Your QuickFIX/J Application](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.3/usage/application.html) for reference.

Comment: (I am relatively new to quickfix)It seems I have not captured session level messages

Comment: And I see only incoming messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start your SocketInitiator, you had to pass it an instance of `quickfix.Application`. In your implementation, you can peek heartbeats in the `toAdmin` and `fromAdmin` implementation.

```java
class YourFixApplication implements Application {
    @Override
    public void fromAdmin( Message message, SessionID sessionID ) {
        MsgType msgType;
        try {
            msgType = (MsgType) message.getHeader( ).getField( new MsgType( ) );
        }
        catch( FieldNotFound e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if( msgType.valueEquals( MsgType.HEARTBEAT ) ) {
            System.out.println( ">>> Heartbeat <<<" );
        }
    }

    // same deal with toAdmin implementation

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TT.'s answer is correct, though some semantics I needed to change for it to work for me:

```
public void ToAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
{
    msgType = (MsgType).message.Header.GetField(new MsgType());

    catch(FieldNotFoundException e)
    {
        //error message
        return;
    }

    if(msgType.Obj.Equals(MsgType.HEARTBEAT))
    {
        // print out wherever or do whatever with the heartbeat msg
    }
}
```